# Github Actions JUnittest Failing: How to get the error report?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, github-actions, error-logging

I have a git repository where some JUnit-Tests fail in github-actions while local JUnit-Tests are ok.

Is there a way to get the failing report?

from https://github.com/k3b/calef/actions/runs/7060398755/job/19219851935

> Task :app:testDebugUnitTest
>
> de.k3b.calef.CalendarFormatterTest > add_germanyShort_ok FAILED
> org.junit.ComparisonFailure at CalendarFormatterTest.java:51
>
> de.k3b.calef.CalendarFormatterTest > add_usShort_ok FAILED
> org.junit.ComparisonFailure at CalendarFormatterTest.java:63
>
> de.k3b.calef.CalendarFormatterTest > add_usShortWithoutTime_ok FAILED
> org.junit.ComparisonFailure at CalendarFormatterTest.java:75
>
> 6 tests completed, 3 failed

> Task :app:testDebugUnitTest FAILED
> [...]
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
>   There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/runner/work/calef/calef/app/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html

How can i read .../testDebugUnitTest/index.html ?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts?

Comment: @jonrsharpe exactly what i was looking for. thanks a lot. If you add "use https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact to your workflow" as answer then i can mark this as answer: